# Can I edit the default Digital Experience site's 'Reset Password' page?

Tags: lightning-experience, visualforce-component, experience-cloud, reset-password, digital-experience

In a Digital Experience site: Administration > Login & Registration > Password Pages > Reset Password.

I'm able to choose between "Default Page" and "Visualforce Page".

Rather than building a brand new Visualforce page from scratch, is there a way of just editing the default page/component?

The URL path is `/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword`.

This is a screenshot of the default page I'm trying to edit:

[image]

Comment: This is a standard page and a jsp page that you cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard page cannot be edited but instead can be replaced by a custom Visualforce page or Flexipage.

There are multiple articles and examples on the implementation.

Flexi Page (Experience Builder Page)
https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/article/Customize-Your-Experience-Site-s-Forgot-Password-Functionality-with-Headless-Identity-APIs

or Visualforce Page

https://github.com/msrivastav13/df23-lwr-cms-demo/blob/main/force-app/main/default/pages/ChangePassword.page

Also, there is learning material in a form of video on this topic

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaNt9VWaqFI